# Running hstart from MSYS

Tags: windows, command-line, uac, msys, git-bash

I'm trying to automate some things on my computer. And here's what I ran into. I'm running this command from MSYS prompt:

```
hstart /elevate "cmd /k netstat -anb"
```

First a message box with title "Failed to create process - Hstart" appears, saying: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/elevate" A new non-elevated console is then opened with a message: "The requested operation requires elevation." It works as expected if run from cmd.exe. What is even happening and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears MSYS performs [automatic paths conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion), if it's to run an executable "not dependent on msys-1.0.dll." So for it work you can double the slash:

```
hstart //elevate "cmd /k netstat -anb"
```

Here are [some](http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/switches%20with%20forward%20slashes) [more](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=426) links, just in case.